# The sum of the power series $\sum_{n\ge 0}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, solution-verification

I want to determine the sum of the power series $$\sum_{n\ge 0}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}$$

Is my try correct ? I know it is not correct since the sum I get is not continuous at $x=0$ but I can't find my mistake. Thanks for your help!

The radius of convergence is clearly $R=1$ hence $\forall x\in (-1,1)$ we have that 
$$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}=\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{x^n}-2\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n+1}}$$
Now $\forall x\in (-1,1)$ $$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{x^n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
and with the condition of $x\not =0$ we have that
$$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$
But $\forall x\in (-1,1)$ $$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}=-\log(1-x)$$

In conclusion, $$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-x}+2\frac{\log(1-x)}{x} & \text{if } x\in (-1,1)-\{0\} \\
0 & \text{if } x=0
\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original series has a non-zero constant term, so your special value for $x = 0$ is not OK.

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}=-1+0+\frac{1}{2}x^2+...$ then the answer is $$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(n-1)x^n}{n+1}}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-x}+2\frac{\log(1-x)}{x} & \text{if } x\in (-1,1)-\{0\} \\
-1 & \text{if } x=0
\end{cases} $$ ?

Comment: @palio: Yes. :) The second summand approaches $-2$ as $x$ approaches $0$, as can be seen in multiple ways (difference quotient for $\log(1-x)$, l'Hôpital's rule, power series, etc.).